# Physical simulation of multiple scenes simultaneously

Tags: 3d-view

I have created physical simulation of objects after initiating them from random positions. I am generating about 9 scenes and would like to view these simulations simultaneously on a blender screen as 3x3 matrix view of scenes together. I guess I might have to use viewport stuff, but didn't find anything concrete on what I wanted to do.

Any pointer would be of great help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to view all three of them in the viewport in real time? Or in the final render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to have blender use multiple windows and have a different scene displayed in each window, only one window will update during playback. To view the same frame in each scene you will need to adjust the current frame displayed in each window.

To watch the animation play from all scenes at once you will need to render them out to video. You can either use the compositor or VSE to combine them.

In the compositor you can use a transform node to scale and position each scene, then alpha over to combine them.

[image]

Using the VSE you want to set the blend type to Alpha Over and adjust the image offset, you will also want to add a transform effect strip to alter the scale of each scene.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. The active scene (bpy.context.active_scene, I think) is shared by the whole blender session.

You could within one scene use several viewports without a problem (check the manual, you click and drag from the \\ section in the lower left corner to create a new viewport and set it to '3d view').

If what you want is a final render with a 3x3 matrix you could render them from separate scenes and merge them using the compositor in a new scene (using translations to move them and scale them to put them at different places on screen).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a separate Scene and use the VSE to load the 9 prerendered videos as image strips.  Each strip would need a different Effect/Transform on it to scale them and adjust their X/Y offsets to tile properly.